# bootstrap fileinput drag and drop image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, bootstrap-4, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3 framework and I included Bootstrap file input in this.

Here is my code:

```js
$('#my-file-upload').fileinput({
  theme: 'fa',
  language: 'en',
  uploadUrl: '#',
  showUpload: false,
  showRemove: true,
  allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'],
  removeFromPreviewOnError: true,
  deleteExtraData: true,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/javanto/jquery-fileinput/3.1.0/dist/jquery.fileinput.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 message-bottom">
  <div class="add-new-box-inner message-layout-bottom">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <label>Upload Image(s)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <div class="file-loading">
            <?php echo $this->Form->file('thread_images[]',['id'=>'my-file-upload','label'=>false,'type'=>'file', 'multiple' => 'multiple']); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All working fine when I browse image and save it.
But Drag and Drop image functionality is not working in this.

Also a big issue is that when I upload an image by browse button and again upload second image using same way then its submit only last image.

what is the problem, can anyone show me the right way?

Comment: What are you using to allow drag and drop?

Comment: I don't know which property is using for this.. please help

Comment: For multiple, try 'multiple' => 'true'?